# Woocommerce image - add image width

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make images in Woocommerce more similar. I have tried Google and i can't find anything regarding my issue.

The images have very different heights and i would like to make all of them 400px. Here: http://afspaerring.adhost-test.dk/vare-kategori/5421/5477/

I have tried with height:400px; width:initial; which worked for some but not all. Is it possible to add some bg or more image width so my images will be 400x300px but without cropping the image but adding white color in stead.

NB. I can't see that the Woocommerce image crop will solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this style; this will fix your height with center position.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img,                         
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product a img {
    width: initial;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto !important;
}
```